# Screen orientation For tablets And devices

Tags: android

I am using the same code for both tablets as well as device,Here is my problem while coming to mobile in both orientation it should load list view, coming to tablet in portrait  it need to load listview and then coming to landscape it should load gridview?

Thanks

I have used this code any one can  help me plz..

```
 Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
                    if((config.screenLayout & Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) ==  
                        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE)); 
                    {
                        this.gridView();    
                    }else{
                        this.listview();
                    }
```

Comment: In your layout design which control u r using????
gridView or ListView ?????

Comment: in layout Xlarge-land i am using gridview and then in layout xlarge-port i am using listview and in normal layout i am using listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using xml for your layouts, all you need to do is create different xml files and place them in the layout folder with appropriate configuration qualifier. See this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) for details.

For you, you would use the following folders:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default"). Listview here
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation. Gallery here
```

Remember, you need to create these folders if they don't exist.

In your code, if you call `setContentView(R.id.my_layout)`, android will use the appropriate layout. Then, you can do a `findViewById()` call where it should return null for the view of the layout not being used. You can do a `findViewById()` on both the ListView and GridView. Based on which view returns null, you can set the member (this.gridView or this.listView) appropriately.

Comment: i have created this layouts.. can u help in writing the above condition

Comment: I think the information I provided is sufficient for you to write the if else statement